# tkinter error "unable to detect undefined names"

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to use tkinter but I got that messages when I write `from tkinter import *` I've tried `import tkinter as tk` for example it works but have to put tk. before every thing , so why `from tkinter import *` does not work ? Python cannot actually read any of its commands it gives me 'NameOfCommand' may be undefined from star impors 
Is that normal? cause a lot of warning messages pop up and python gives me no automatic complete of a sentence as usual and as I study in the tutorials

```
from math import *
x=ceil(5.6)
print(x) # prints 6
```

I've recently installed python 3.6 , even though math gives me the same warning says ' 'Ceil' may be undefined or defined from star imports:math  '

Comment: " it works but have to put tk. before every thing" it's a tiny inconvenience for the fact that you know which module the method comes from. I suggest you don't try Java.

Comment: How about example code to help with your explanation?

Comment: edited please check the post again

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that shows that when you use `from tkinter import *` that tkinter classes and commands cannot be found.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, formatted as code ideally.

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs, the correct import statement is:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

Does that work?

Comment: Nope, the same warning appears

Comment: I was using python 2.6 for long time, I've recently installed 3.6 , I think this error is related to the new version, even though math library gives me the same error , knowing that tkinter._test() works meaning that the library is there, but those warning messages plus python does not complete of recommend the rest of command as usual annoy me

Comment: `Tkinter` is the library's name for python 2, whereas `tkinter` is the library's name in python 3. I don't see how the above answer's helpful.